# Donut chart image icons centering - Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highchart pie-donut chart for a project and I'm facing issues regarding the centering of icons within different slices of the donut. I am having 3 slices within the donut chart, and for each slice particular icon (using the URL) needs to be rendered.

Here's the specific code that attaches the icon to the corresponding slice of donut.

```
var chartIconsUrl = {
 'suitcase': 'https://s18.postimg.org/jju1bg1o9/suitcase.png',
 'home': 'https://s18.postimg.org/xnrqpb9rt/home.png',
 'notes': 'https://s13.postimg.org/a5r39jv8n/notes.png'
}

dataLabels : {
  enabled : true,
  useHTML : true,
  formatter : function() {
   if(this.y!=0)
     return '<img src = ' + chartIconsUrl[this.key] + '><img>';
   },
   distance : -30
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dsharm/anva3gaz/.

Please note that icons are rendered at different positions on different browsers, in IE icons are shifted down. I have cross browser compatibility as my requirement as well.

Edit:

```
formatter: function(){
 return '<img style="width:20px; height: 20px" src =' + chartIconsUrl[this.key] + '><img>';
}
```

I can't directly add the width, height, x and y to the label as I have requirement of variable slice size i.e., y values can change dynamically.

Comment: Set height and width properties of the img. You can also adjust data labels position by setting x, y properties.https://jsfiddle.net/anva3gaz/2/

Comment: @morganfree Even after setting the width and height icons are not rendered properly in IE, somewhat shifted down. I have the requirement in which size of the slice i.e., y value will change so I can't directly set the label by setting x,y. I am looking for the programmatic icons centering for all the cases.

Comment: Fix img tag and delete the unnecessary one. I guess you know how big the img should be, if yes with height, width and correctly closed tag it will get positioned correctly.https://jsfiddle.net/anva3gaz/8/